# How to manipulate the DOM to add to a table

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I currently have a function that I'm assigning to a button, the general idea is each time it creates a table and an image, and while I understand how to change an img.src or textContent, I'm struggling with the table.   Below is a working function to pass through an object and create a table by creating elements and appending it's keys/values.

```
function genAlbum(object) {
let headingNames = Object.keys(object.tracks[0]);
let table = document.getElementById('tracks');
let headings = document.createElement('tr');
headingNames.forEach((arr) => {
    let tableHeader = document.createElement('th');
    tableHeader.textContent = arr;
    headings.appendChild(tableHeader);
});
table.appendChild(headings);
let vals = Object.values(object.tracks);
vals.forEach(function (album) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let properties in album) {
        let cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.textContent = album[properties];
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
});

return table;
```

}

However, I'd like to have it so the user can click the button and it just refreshes with a new table each time, instead of creating multiple.   The objects are different lengths, so how would I set up my HTML to pass through 10-15 rows without appending?

Just to be clear I want a new table each time the function is run, not to keep generating multiple.

Comment: maybe clean the table before the append statements? ``table.innerHTML = ''``

Comment: This works!  Thanks, I'm still curious if there's a way to do this otherwise but thanks for your help.